# Error "Could not find class android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable" occurs while changing FAB icon

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview, rippledrawable

I have a Fab which I am using in order to hide or show BottomNavigationBar in my pplication. Everything works fine in andorid 7.0 (1080p), but when I am trying to run the app in android 4.4 (720p), FAB is not visible.

Also, when I am hiding or showing the bottomNavigationBar, I am moving the FAB down and UP respectively, and changing the icon on FAB in order to make it look a little better.

This is my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_show" />

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <!-- frame layout content -->

</FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="3dp">

       <!-- frame layout content -->

    </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:itemIconTint="#fff"
            app:itemTextColor="#fff"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code I have in Activity

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(GONE);

                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_show));

                final ObjectAnimator moveFab
                        = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Y, fab.getY(), 0);
                moveFab.setDuration(300);
                moveFab.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                moveFab.start();

            }else if(bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() == View.GONE){

                bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_hide));

                final ObjectAnimator moveFab
                        = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Y, fab.getY(), -150);
                moveFab.setDuration(300);
                moveFab.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                moveFab.start();

            }

        }
    });
```

My log cat says

```
Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

Am Using something which is not supported by android 4.4 or I am just making any mistake?

I have already gone through many questions with similar titles, Nothing seems relevant.

Comment: Have you tried removing `app:rippleColor`in 4.4 and then run?

Comment: @AyushKhare Yes I have tried that.